# Jquery Cookie return undefined [only in ie]

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

Iam using jquery cookie .cookie return undefined in IE (only one machine).help me to resolve this issue.

JS Code

```
var cookie = {};
cookie["version"] = 1;
cookie["columnstate"] = { "width": 100, "hidden": true };
cookie["columnstate1"] = { "width": 200, "hidden": false };
$.cookie("state", JSON.stringify(cookie), { expires: 365 });

$("#getCookie").click(function () {
    alert($.cookie("state"));               
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="getCookie">Get Cookie</button>
```

Comment: What version of IE?  What errors show in the debug console in IE?  What version of jQuery are you running?  What version of the cookie library?

Comment: Iam using IE11,Jquery-1.11.2 and jquery cookie v1.4.1 and there is no issue in console.

Answer (score 0):

This is working with me on IE8

```
var cookie = {};
cookie["version"] = 1;
cookie["columnstate"] = { "width": 100, "hidden": true };
cookie["columnstate1"] = { "width": 200, "hidden": false };
jQuery.cookie("state", JSON.stringify(cookie), { expires: 365 });

alert(jQuery.cookie("state"));
```

I am using **jquery.cookie.js** v1.4.1. Which IE version you are trying.

Comment: iam also using jquery cookie V1.4.1 .issue only occur in one machine

Comment: May be issue is with browser cookie settings on that mc.

Comment: I deleted the browser cookie .but it return same issue

Comment: Check if cookie is enabled or not. Perhaps browser is not storing any cookie.

Comment: Posting the same code as in the question is not an answer. If you want to say that it works as written, that should just be a comment.